# Better way to work around lack of vwscanf in Visual C++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, variadic-functions

The C++11 standard specifies that `vwscanf` is available via header `<cwchar>` (and therefore `<wchar.h>`). However it seems to be lacking in Visual C++. With that function I could write …

```
inline int scanf( CodingValue const* format, ... )
{
    va_list args;
    va_start( args, format );
    return ::vwscanf( format->ptr(), args );
}
```

but without it, i.e. with Visual C++ 10.0, which also appears to lack support for C++11 variadic templates, I’m reduced to writing …

```
inline int scanf(
    CodingValue const* format,
    void* a01 = 0, void* a02 = 0, void* a03 = 0, void* a04 = 0, void* a05 = 0,
    void* a06 = 0, void* a07 = 0, void* a08 = 0, void* a09 = 0, void* a10 = 0,
    void* a11 = 0, void* a12 = 0
    )
{
    int const   nArgs = !!a01 + !!a02 + !!a03 + !!a04 + !!a05 + !!a06 +
                        !!a07 + !!a08 + !!a09 + !!a10 + !!a11 + !!a12;
    BasicCodingValue const* const   f   = format->ptr();

    switch( nArgs )
    {
    case  0:    return ::wscanf( f );
    case  1:    return ::wscanf( f,a01 );
    case  2:    return ::wscanf( f,a01,a02 );
    case  3:    return ::wscanf( f,a01,a02,a03 );
    case  4:    return ::wscanf( f,a01,a02,a03,a04 );
    case  5:    return ::wscanf( f,a01,a02,a03,a04,a05 );
    case  6:    return ::wscanf( f,a01,a02,a03,a04,a05,a06 );
    case  7:    return ::wscanf( f,a01,a02,a03,a04,a05,a06,a07 );
    case  8:    return ::wscanf( f,a01,a02,a03,a04,a05,a06,a07,a08 );
    case  9:    return ::wscanf( f,a01,a02,a03,a04,a05,a06,a07,a08,a09 );
    case 10:    return ::wscanf( f,a01,a02,a03,a04,a05,a06,a07,a08,a09,a10 );
    case 11:    return ::wscanf( f,a01,a02,a03,a04,a05,a06,a07,a08,a09,a10,a11 );
    case 12:    return ::wscanf( f,a01,a02,a03,a04,a05,a06,a07,a08,a09,a10,a11,a12 );
    }
}
```

Or, I could do some assembly, as I did like 15 years ago when I encountered similar (or perhaps the same) problem, but that does not feel quite right.

Can you suggest some better way?

Comment: You *could*, but why the hell would you want to?

Comment: Check out http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-AU/vclanguage/thread/b043efbc-b4d8-413b-bd21-937bd0d5dd8e

Comment: @EmileCormier - these aren't references or anything you couldn't do in C, so I don't think that's a problem here.

Comment: @Emile: thanks! I saw that a few days ago, though. The main stumbling block: that to access the underlying implementation function one must link with the static runtime library. Cheers,

Comment: I didn't really read that discussion. Just pasted the link here in case it helps! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand it's not an error to call a variadic function with extra (i.e. more than asked for) arguments in C (and possibly in C++, although I've yet to locate a definitive statement either way on that).

The best I've got on the C++ side so far is 5.2.2 [expr.call]:

> A function can be declared to accept fewer arguments (by declaring
>   default arguments (8.3.6)) or more arguments (by using the ellipsis,
>   ..., or a function parameter pack (8.3.5)) than the number of
>   parameters in the function definition (8.4)

18.10 [support.runtime] defers to the ISO C 4.8.1.1 on the subject of restrictions for `va_start()`.

I can't see anywhere that says "you must not pass extra arguments", so it seems that it wouldn't be unreasonable to assume that it's not prohibited.

If it's not legal in C++ to give extra arguments then you can use C++ to handle the default arguments still and call a C function with the defaults having been "filled out" so that you only ever call the one C function, regardless of how many arguments were given.

So in C++ you'd do:

```
extern "C" {
  int real_scanf(
        const char* format,
        void* a01, void* a02, void* a03, void* a04, void* a05,
        void* a06, void* a07, void* a08, void* a09, void* a10,
        void* a11, void* a12
        );
}

inline int scanf(
    CodingValue const* format,
    void* a01 = 0, void* a02 = 0, void* a03 = 0, void* a04 = 0, void* a05 = 0,
    void* a06 = 0, void* a07 = 0, void* a08 = 0, void* a09 = 0, void* a10 = 0,
    void* a11 = 0, void* a12 = 0
    )
{
    BasicCodingValue const* const   f   = format->ptr();
    return real_scanf( f,a01,a02,a03,a04,a05,a06,a07,a08,a09,a10,a11,a12 );
}
```

and then in C you could do:

```
int real_scanf(
    const char* format,
    void* a01, void* a02, void* a03, void* a04, void* a05,
    void* a06, void* a07, void* a08, void* a09, void* a10,
    void* a11, void* a12
    )
{
    return wscanf( format,a01,a02,a03,a04,a05,a06,a07,a08,a09,a10,a11,a12 );
}
```

Comment: +1 Nice, but a01 to a12 needs to be default-valued as in Alf's question

Comment: @mloskot - the idea of that part was that they explicitly *weren't* default valued so it could be a strictly C function, that can be called by a C++, default valued function if required to work around any difference between the C and C++ rules on such functions.

Comment: Formal support: my C99 draft says in §7.24.2.11 that `wscanf` is equivalent to `fwscanf` with argument `stdin`; then §7.24.2.2 about `fwscanf` says "If the format is exhausted while arguments remain, the excess arguments are evaluated (as always) but are otherwise ignored." Cheers, & thanks,

Comment: awoodland Without default values, it won't compile. I clarified it in answer below/above based on yours.

Comment: @mloskot: I think you're missing something in this answer.  awoodland isn't sure if it is legal to call `wscanf` with too many parameters, but knows it is okay in C.  So he suggests compiling a C function that takes a ton of parameters, and forwards them all to `wscanf`, then in C++ write a function with a ton of default parameters that forwards to this C function.  In other words, it will compile just fine, because it is never called except by a function that provides all the appropriate parameters.

Comment: Of course, the C++ standard simply defers to the C standard when it comes to these sorts of functions, so this is all for naught, and simply forwarding them all directly is perfectly kosher

Comment: I selected this as the "solution" since it was first.

Answer (score 1):

My version of [awoodland](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7997539/better-way-to-work-around-lack-of-vwscanf-in-visual-c/7998091#7998091)'s answer: default-valued arguments are required:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cassert>

template <typename CodingValue>
int scanf(CodingValue const* format,
    void* a01 = 0, void* a02 = 0, void* a03 = 0, void* a04 = 0, void* a05 = 0,
    void* a06 = 0, void* a07 = 0, void* a08 = 0, void* a09 = 0, void* a10 = 0,
    void* a11 = 0, void* a12 = 0)
{
    return wscanf( format,a01,a02,a03,a04,a05,a06,a07,a08,a09,a10,a11,a12 );
}

int main()
{
    int v(0);
    int rc = scanf<wchar_t>(L"%d", &v);
    assert(1 == rc);
    return 0;
}
```

Please, refer to [Dennis Zickefoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7997539/better-way-to-work-around-lack-of-vwscanf-in-visual-c/7998091#7998091) comments above for some background details.

Answer (score 0):

There is an implementation of `int vwscanf(format, ...)` with VS2010.

File = wscanf.c

Directory = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\crt\src